# Immersive Reader onPreferencesChanged event not firing as preferences are changing

Tags: javascript, immersive-reader

In this javascript code which calls the immersive reader SDK, the onExit fires as expected, but the onPreferencesChanged never fires.  What am I missing here?

```
async function LaunchImmersiveReader(title) {
    const data = {
        title: title,
        chunks: [{
            content: title,
            lang: 'en'
        }]
    };

    const token = await getImmersiveReaderTokenAsync();
    const subdomain = await getImmersiveReaderSubdomainAsync();

    const options = {            
        onPreferencesChanged: onPreferencesChangedCallback,
        onExit: exitCallback
    };
    

    ImmersiveReader.launchAsync(token, subdomain, data, options);
}

function exitCallback() {
// this fires as I click the immersive reader exit/back button
}


function onPreferencesChangedCallback(value) {
// this never fires as I change font, size, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of the SDK are you using? The preferences callback is part of 1.1.0

I did notice that a lot of our sample projects and documentation is using 1.0.0 still, which might be leading to the confusion

Comment: Thank you...that was it.  I changed my version to 1.1.0 and the callback fires.

Comment: Great! Thanks for posting the question, we're now updating all of our samples & docs to be more clear. If you could mark my answer as accepted that would be great too thanks!